# Best way to manage filer form and result page

Tags: symfony

What's the best way to manage filter page and result page in Symfony?
I have a controller that manage filter form and execute query. The result of this query must pass in another controller action. The result must show in another controller action because I used knp_paginator. If I render the result in same controller action of filter form, when change page the controller show filter form and not result.

Comment: I usually implements all in a single action method, consider to pass the form filter result in GET method for better handle pagination. Take a look how the `PUGXGeneratorBundle` works [here](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXGeneratorBundle). That generate simple CRUD using KNP and LEXIK for filter, then you can simply use same approach for your needed. Hope this help.

Comment: let me know if yuo need same example about

Comment: I spent all afternoon but I did. Thank you for availability :-)

Comment: great! If you have time, consider to share your solution as answer to the question

Answer (score 3):

this is the approach that I used:

Action for create find form:

```
public function findAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createFindForm($request);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if(($form->isSubmitted() && !$request->isXmlHttpRequest()))
    {
        if(($this->isValidFindForm($form) && $form->isValid()))
        {
            $parm = $request->request->get('findForm');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('list_documents',$parm));
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
            'myBundle:Documents:document\document_find.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}

private function createFindForm(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(
                new findDocumentType(
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
                    $request
                ),
                null,
                array(
                    'action' => $this->generateUrl('find_documents'),
                    'method' => 'POST',
                )
            );
    return $form;
}
```

I used $parm = $request->request->get('findForm'); to get the querystring. "findForm" is the name of my filter form.

The redirecting action :

```
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $documents = $this->searchDocument($request);
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $documents,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)
    );
    return $this->render(
            'myBundle:Documents:document\document_list.html.twig',
            array('pagination' => $pagination)
    );
}
```

The request is passed to search function (request contains querystring)
In search action:

```
private function searchDocument(Request $request)
{
    $parm = $request->query;
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('docliteBundle:Document\\document');
    $query = $repository
                ->createQueryBuilder('d');
 ....
```

With $request->query->get() I have access to all parameter.

Hope this help someone.

P.S. for the pagination I used  [KNP_paginator](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/templates.md)